# sudo: eval: command not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, macos-mojave

I have installed minikube on my system and `minikube start` works as expected for me. When I want to use local docker images and hence trying to run sudo `eval $(minikube docker-env)`.

This gives me an error:

> sudo: eval: command not found

Any guidance or solution for this? I am running this on MacOS Mojave.

Comment: Why are you trying to run this command with sudo?

Comment: because minikube was installed with sudo. But it works now!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use `sudo eval $(minikube docker-env)`, `sudo: eval: command not found` this means `eval` not found. `eval` is an built-in in shell, so when `sudo` without `-s` it will surely tell you this error, like next:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/777$ sudo eval
sudo: eval: command not found
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/777$ sudo -s eval
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/777$
```

- If you want to execute with root account:

  ```
  $ sudo -s -H
  $ eval $(minikube docker-env)
  ```
- If you just intend to execute with current account:

  ```
  $ eval $(minikube docker-env)
  ```

Comment: Another flavor would be `eval $(sudo minikube docker-env)`

Answer (score 2):

Ran into same issue while setting up the jenkins workflow. Below solution worked for me:

Instead of:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Try using:

```
sudo -s eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Answer (score 1):

Others coming here could get this error for an entirely different reason as the accepted answer. In my case the minikube cluster was not running. The error you get in this case is also *command not found*.

Just run the command: `minikube docker-env` and if you get the error: *The control plane node must be running for this command* just start it using `minikube start` and re-run the command `eval $(minikube docker-env)`. It should work this time.

Answer (score 1):

For me the trouble was in quotes:
instead of
`eval  $( "${cm}" )`

put this

```
eval  $"( "${cm}" )"
```

Comment: I had a similar problem in which `eval $(/sbin/blkid -o udev /dev/sdb1)` was giving me back `bash: Data: command not found` because one of the USB key identifiers had spaces like this: `ID_FS_PARTLABEL=Main Data Partition` Your solution to use quotes like this: `eval $"(/sbin/blkid -o udev /dev/sdb1)"` worked for me *from the command line* but **NOT** from a script. From a script I needed to use `sed` to enclose any property values that contained spaces in single quotes: `eval $(/sbin/blkid -o udev /dev/sdb1|sed 's/=/="/'|sed 's/$/"/')` then the `eval $(...)` command worked from a script.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was spacing issues with non-breaking spaces. You can visualize these using following command:

```
LC_ALL=C cat -v .zshrc
```

removing that non-breaking space "M-BM- " solved my problem.

Thanks to [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63093946/while-setting-up-pyenv-getting-eval-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

> echo `ssh-agent -s` > .tmp_ssh_agent
>
> source .tmp_ssh_agent

this worked for me instead of eval
(May help you)